# Split string by substring not char

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net, string, split

I have searched the site before asking but none of the solution I've found make sense with my problem.

Firstly I have a string which is something like:

```
Dim someString As String = "<object>sometext</object><object>sometext</object><object>sometext</object>"
```

I am trying to get it split into an array of string like so:

```
stringArray 0 --> "<object>sometext</object>"
stringArray 1 --> "<object>sometext</object>"
stringArray 2 --> "<object>sometext</object>"
```

The methods I have tried for splitting the text remove the delimiter from the result which is not what I want since it then invalidates the code.

Comment: I presume you want to parse XML so. That would make your task much easier. Here's some reading on using XML in VB.net


http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4826/XML-File-Parsing-in-VB-NET

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1440433

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. The string is actually stored in a database like this so it's not from an xml file. It seems like a lot of extra code to use XML just to split them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bit pseudo code as I'm not sure of the exact VB syntax, but could you try forcing a character at the end of each  so something like:

```
Dim someString As String = "<object>sometext</object><object>sometext</object><object>sometext</object>"
var stringToSpilt = someString.Replace("</object>","</object>~")
var splitObjects = stringToSpilt.Split("~")
```

If the "object" could be any text then RegEx replace would do this, but as the guys above have commented, if it's XML splitting it'll be more involved than this.

Comment: Replace does not work in place. You need to re-assign it: `someString = someString.Replace("</object>","</object>~")`

Comment: Ah I like that idea, just one extra line of code, thanks Mr.PieFace!

Answer (score 0):

Using IndexOf and working with a List(Of String), no hidden strings fragmentation

```
Dim someString As String = "<object>sometext</object><object>sometext</object><object>sometext</object>"
Dim result = new List(Of String)()
Dim pos = 0
Dim init = 0
Dim len = "</object>".Length
do 
   pos = someString.IndexOf("</object>", init)
   if pos <> -1 Then
      result.Add(someString.Substring(init, pos +  len - init))
      init = pos + len + 1
   End If
Loop while pos <> -1
```